Where are the miniature molded case circuit breaker trip characteristics defined?
Some vendors specify a "trip-characteristic" for their miniature circuit breakers with a letter.  B, C, K, Z specifically.  From what I gather these seem to be standard designations possibly defined by IEC.  Which standard, if any, defines these characteristics?  I'm specifically concerned with the Z characteristic, which appears to be set to trip instantaneously at 2-3 times the rated current.

IEC 60898-1 is the standard for domestic miniature circuit breakers, while IEC 60947-2 covers them in commercial premises.  IEC 61009-1 is the standard for RCBOs (MCB+RCD/GFCI).  These are often transcribed into national regulations - eg EN 60898-1 or BS EN 60898-1.
The standards themselves are paywalled, but you can find various third party explanations of them.

Thank you.  I was specifically looking to see which standard provided a definition of these tripping characteristics by letter designator. I have access to some of these standards, so I will review them to see if the details I'm looking for are included.  If you happen to have access to these standards and can provide a reference section, that would be appreciated as well.

@martij7 Looks like I can see BS EN60898-1:2019 (track changes version). There's no mention of Z-curve or K-curve circuit breakers in the standard like there are B-curve, C-curve and D-curve. (The standard calls them 'B-type' instead of 'B-curve').  Section 5.3.5 lists the different types and their instantaneous trip characteristics.
